# How to flip two words in a sentence in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

How to flip two words in a sentence in java like

Input: "hi how are you doing today jane"

Output: "how  hi you are today doing jane"

what I tried:

```
String s = "hi how are you doing today jane";
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] splitted = s.split("\\s+");
    int n = splitted.length;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        al.add(splitted[i]);
    }
  for(int i=0; i<n-1; i=i+2) {
    System.out.print(al.get(i+1)+" "+al.get(i)+" ");
  }
  if((n%2) != 0) {
          System.out.print(al.get(n - 1));
      }
```

output I'm getting:
"how hiyou aretoday doing"

Comment: (1) Look at your `System.out.print` statement - you're only putting in one space, whereas you really need a second space after `al.get(i)`. (2) You need a way to account for the last element, if `n` is odd (since what you've written prints them in pairs). This could be accomplished by a simple `if` statement after the `for` loop

Comment: This question is way better than the last one. Thanks for taking people's opinion into account. +1.

Comment: How do you know which two words to flip?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy If I add another space, jane wouldn't be printed.

Comment: @JaneF Just add at the end after the loop  `if((n % 2) != 0) System.out.print(a1.get(n - 1));` which can be translated to "if n is not pair, print the last element".

Comment: @PaulLemarchand  `for(int i=0; i<n-1; i=i+2) {
       if((n%2) != 0) {
        System.out.print(al.get(n - 1));
       }
     }`        this prints `janejanejane` as output

Comment: @JaneF After the loop I said. Look at your braces.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand  Now It worked, Is there any better way of doing this? since two for loops are being used

Comment: look at @Andreas answer, it's great.

Comment: There are better ways to do this although your approach of splitting into array of words is basically sane. But. The art of debugging consists of BEING the computer, of figuring exactly what the computer does when you give it commands. You need to really READ the code you write as a computer would. You need to account for ALL the observed behavior (you need to understand exactly what the computer is doing at all times). That will bring you to understanding what is wrong withe the code. Then the next step is how to fix it.

Comment: Most people on SO are capable of doing this work. You will get the answer you ask for. But this will not develop your own skills at debugging/understanding code. And without those skills, you can't call yourself a programmer. Please, invest some time in training yourself to do this work on your own.

Comment: @Arkadiy  You shouldn't have deleted your answer, I would have accepted it. I have noted yours in my book

Comment: `String[] words = "hi how are you doing today jane".split("\\s+");
         String[] result = new String[words.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i = i+2) {
           if (words.length - i  >= 2) { 
             result[i] = words[i+1];
             result[i+1] = words[i];
           } else {
             result[i] = words[i];
           }
         }
         System.out.println(String.join(" ", result));
`

Comment: The answer by @PaulLemarchand is better. It does the same thing I did and does it using more built-in language tools. My alternative that uses arrays does not get to play with `Collections.swap()` Oh, and he does not use a spare array (exercise for the reader - change my code to avoid spare array). Of course, the actual amount of garbage created is way higher when you use `ArrayList` and streams.

Comment: Also, rather than putting it in comment, make it your own answer (after you get rid of the spare array :) )

Comment: Thanks @Arkadiy. You're right about streams, I changed for `String.join()`, which also seems more readable.

Answer (score 3):

As you asked to do with only one loop and without extensive use of regex, here is another solution using `Collections.swap`:

```
String s = "hi how are you doing today jane";
List<String> splitted = new ArrayList<>(List.of(s.split("\\s+")));

for(int i = 0; i < splitted.size() - 1; i += 2)
    Collections.swap(splitted, i, i + 1);
s = String.join(" ", splitted);
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

> how hi you are today doing jane

Comment: Edit: Usage of `String.join()` instead of `stream API`, which seems more readable and optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `split()` which takes a regex, it would seem that using regex is a valid solution, so use it:

```
replaceAll("(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\w+)", "$3$2$1")
```

*Explanation*

```
(\\w+)   Match first word, and capture it as group 1
(\\W+)   Match the characters between the 2 words, and capture them as group 2
(\\w+)   Match second word, and capture it as group 3
$3$2$1   Replace the above with the 3 groups in reverse order
```

*Example*

```
System.out.println("hi how are you doing today jane".replaceAll("(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\w+)", "$3$2$1"));
```

*Output*

```
how hi you are today doing jane
```

Note: Since your code used `split("\\s+")`, your definition of a "word" is a sequence of non-whitespace characters. To use that definition of a word, change the regex to:

```
replaceAll("(\\S+)(\\s+)(\\S+)", "$3$2$1")
```

Comment: I'm looking to do it logically , not by regex

Comment: "Now you have two problems" :)

Comment: @Arkadiy I do like that quote, but it really doesn't apply here, since in this case a regex is actually a simpler solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want old-school fori loop and bufor/temp value solution, here you are:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hi how are you doing today jane";
    String flip = flip(s);
    System.out.println(flip);
}

private static String flip(String sentence) {

    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split("\\s+"));

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i += 2) {
        if (i + 1 < words.size()) {
            String tmp = words.get(i + 1);
            words.set(i + 1, words.get(i));
            words.set(i, tmp);
        }
    }
    return words.stream().map(String::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

However  [Pauls solultion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56064520/6834044) is way better since it is java, and we are no more in the stone age era :)

Comment: old-fashioned answers are easy to understand for everyone including students and dummies